# Solve $y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2\cos x(1-\sin x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given differential equation.

$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2\cos x(1-\sin x)$

Can anyone give some hint as how to initiate the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2.cosx(1-sinx)$$
or
$$\frac{y-x\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}=cosx(1-sinx)$$
which is
$$\frac{d(\frac{x}{y})}{dx}=cosx(1-sinx)$$
Thus
$$\int{d(\frac{x}{y})}=\int{cosx(1-sinx)}dx$$
which can be easily solved.